# Retrive and display data from a database in a particular order with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a data (in tabular form) that look like as follows

```
1 2 3

     4     

5 0 6

8
```

This table contains three column and four rows and 12 cells.but all cells do not have value.i have stored data in this table to a database entering zero in the place of empty cells. but it result in the wastage of lot of space in database. I need to enter only non-zero values to my database and must be shown as the above table when retrieved.

Comment: Ouch, no need to yell!

Comment: And the yelling is solved with a simple edit and @podiluska Thanks for making me laugh :)

Comment: HAHAHA SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Comment: It's not the bad English Nikki, it's the *CAPS LOCK IS CRUISE CONTROL FOR COOL* that people are annoyed with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty simple:

Store the `row` and `column` values in their own separate columns, along with a `value` column that holds the cell value.

You'll never enter non-zero or blank database values.

When you retrieve the values, populate them into a multidimensional array:

```
$table[ $row['row'] ][ $row['col'] ] = $row['value'];
```

Comment: BUT NICKB CAN YOU PLAESE CLEAR YOUR CONCEPT